# One template - Many pages : can I use a dynamic sitemap?

Tags: javascript, ajax, seo

I have an application for searching recommendations on different institutions. 
The app itself is a single-page app based on AJAX, but to simulate statefulness the URL's are dynamically changing through the History.replaceState() method.

The URL which I'm injecting also exists as a separate HTML page, so when one copies the URL He can reuse it to load directly the recommendation he seeks for. This template is also populated by JavaScript.

the URL structure is pretty straight-forward:

```
   http://mattat.org.il/ci/index.php/search/show_full/nsrecommendation/[idOfRec]
```

The recommendations themselves are clearly static, that is they do not update.

How do I go about SEO if I want all the content to be indexed by Google. Do I have to manually upload a fat sitemap with all the ID's and update it every time a new recommendation is added? or is there a more elegant way of doing it, such as a dynamic sitemap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways of handling that.

1. Rely on ability of google crawler to reach (and index) all of your pages ('cause keep in mind that sitemaps are suppose only to tip google crawler, no to control it).
2. Like you said - generate sitemap and update it regulary when there are entries to add or remove.

The first solution assumes that somewhere on your page you have (and if not, you should) index of all recomendations and/or there are links from one recomendation to another so google can crawl through those links.

Keep in mind that providing sitemap won't necessarily mean, that google will simply jump on all of those links - indexing the whole content may take some time as it relies on google mysterious algorithms (tm).

UPDATE FROM THE OP:

I ended up using a sitemap generator I've downloaded from [here](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/standalone-google-sitemap-generator.html).
It allows for unlimited number of pages, and a Cron Job option to periodically update the Sitemap.